# Firebase - Extraer una Imagen o una miniatura de un video mp4 subido al STORAGE o el momento que se sube el archivo .mp4

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Pasé unos días investigando y leyendo artículos de firebase, firebase Cloud Storage, nodejs, canvas, javascript, apis, etc. Pero lo que encontré se complica mas de que lo que debería y seguramente habrá maneras más fáciles de hacerlo. ¿Alguien puede guiarme para obtener una fácil solución?

Podría implementarse con nodejs desde el backend en el momento en que reciba la URL de descarga o con javascript desde el frontend en el momento en que cargue el archivo video**.mp4** , el vídeo no tiene que llegar a reproducirse durante el proceso y nunca estará en una etiqueta `<video>`.

La subida del vídeo se hace con **File** con el método `.put(file)` de Firebase,  mediante un **blob** se abrirían muchas posibilidades trabajando con canvas pero sigo pensando que tendría que haber una manera más fácil y rápida de hacerlo con la ayuda de las Firebase-tools o alguna herramienta relacionada con Firebase. También pensé que algún experto de **Firebase** me respondería rápidamente con alguna manera de obtener la imagen mediante el URL de descarga que te proporciona el **STORAGE**, pero sigo investigando y buscando a alguien que pueda guiarme un poco por que estoy un poco verde con el Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Desde javascript se puede crear la miniatura utilizando el método canvas drawImage()

Esta sería la forma de implementarlo:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function crearMiniaturaVideo(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls></video><br/>
<button onclick="crearMiniaturaVideo()">Crear Miniatura</button> <br/><br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas> <br/><br/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si conozco el método con canvas pero esto se debe de hacer desde una etiqueta `<video>`  yo ademas de  embeber el vídeo en un div  también necesito crear la imagen mucho antes de que pueda ser visualizado cuando se termina de cargar el vídeo desde la web al storage o cuando lo acepto y publico desde el backend con **nodejs**, por eso realmente estoy buscando un método que se adapte mas a mis necesidades, gracias por la respuesta @Eduardo , un saludo!